# javascript not checking condition properly in case of span tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form and a span. When i click on the submit button, it calls a function.

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <span id="msg_check">
    checkingfgr
  </span>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="save" onclick="return valid()" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function valid() {
    a = document.getElementById("msg_check").innerHTML;
    if (a = "checking") {
      alert("hi")
    } else {
      return false;   
    }
  }
</script>
```

Now what i want is that if span contains checking then it should alert else return false...but it is alerting in all cases it is not going to the else part. When i am putting something else in the span tag still it is alerting, it is not calling function properly.

Comment: `a=="checking"` not `=`

Comment: `=` is for assignment, `==` is for comparison.

Comment: If you write your code in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) you will see a warning at `if(a="checking")`.

Comment: i did that also but its not checking

Comment: You should write JavaScript in the JavaScript box, not inside the HTML; like in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kocipugu/1/).

Answer (score 1):

it is going in if, because `if(a="checking")` you are assigning a not comparing, so thats the reason its goes always in `if` block

use

```
if(a=="checking")
{
alert("hi");
}
```

if it containg `checking`

```
if (a.indexOf("checking") > -1) {
    alert('Hi');
}
```

Comment: its not alerting anything

Comment: @user3778790, get rid of the spaces around the word "checking". In your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether the span contains (instead of equals) `checking`, you need the following.

```
if (a.indexOf("checking") > -1) {
    alert('Hi');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For comparing the value of `"a"` with `"checking"`, use the following code :

```
if(a==="checking") {
   alert("hi")
}
else {
   alert("hello");
   return false;   
}
```